# How can I extract bounding boxes in a row-wise manner using R?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have an sf object containing multiple (square) polygons of a grid. What I like would be to get a column containing for each polygon the four values, which define the bounding box (bottom-left and top-right).

Here is an example for the the canton of Zurich in Switzerland:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)             

ch <- getData('GADM', country = 'CH', level = 1)

ch_grid <- ch %>% 
   st_as_sf() %>% 
   filter(NAME_1 == "Zürich") %>%
   st_make_grid(cellsize = 0.1, what = "polygons")
```

This gives me a 6x7 grid. Now I'm looking for a way to get for each of the square polygons the two coordinate pairs, which define the bounding box - preferably in a new column.

I hope it's clear what I mean. I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Your `ch_grid` here is an `sfc` object and so can't have a new column. Did you want to convert it via `st_sf` first into an sf data frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your `ch_grid` `sfc` object, this one-liner:

```
> ch_grid_df = cbind(st_sf(geometry=ch_grid),do.call(rbind,lapply(ch_grid, st_bbox)))
```

creates an `sf` data frame with four columns as required:

```
> ch_grid_df
Simple feature collection with 42 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 8.358933 ymin: 47.16357 xmax: 9.058933 ymax: 47.76357
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
First 10 features:
       xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax                        ch_grid
1  8.358933 47.16357 8.458933 47.26357 POLYGON ((8.358933 47.16357...
2  8.458933 47.16357 8.558933 47.26357 POLYGON ((8.458933 47.16357...
3  8.558933 47.16357 8.658933 47.26357 POLYGON ((8.558933 47.16357...
4  8.658933 47.16357 8.758933 47.26357 POLYGON ((8.658933 47.16357...
5  8.758933 47.16357 8.858933 47.26357 POLYGON ((8.758933 47.16357...
6  8.858933 47.16357 8.958933 47.26357 POLYGON ((8.858933 47.16357...
```

This only uses base R functions and so will be robust against the vagaries of time and fashion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply and the very efficient solution. I didn't expect it to be that short ;-)

Comment: "only uses base R" - and `sf`.

Answer (score 1):

The [newest tidyverse pattern](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dplyr-alternatives-to-rowwise/8071) for iterating over rows is using `dplyr::mutate(new_col = purrr::map(existing_col, func))`, which works well with spatial objects including the `geometry` column in `sf` objects.

So something like this to return a bounding box and a grid layout for each row:

```
library(purrr)

ch_grid <- ch %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  mutate(bbox = map(geometry, st_bbox),
         grid = map(geometry, ~ st_make_grid(., cellsize = 0.1, what = "polygons")))
```

If don't want to use `purrr::map()`, `lapply()` can be subbed in:

```
ch_grid <- ch %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  mutate(bbox = lapply(geometry, st_bbox),
         grid = lapply(geometry, st_make_grid, cellsize = 0.1, what = "polygons"))
```